# VB to C# in InStrRev

Tags: c#

I need to rewrite

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Mid(pReturn, (InstrRev(pReturn, ".") + 1), (pReturn).Length)).Length > 4
```

to C# but can't find a concise solution for InstrRev.

How can I convert this line?

Comment: [`string.LastIndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`String.LastIndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would be the equivalent.

Comment: IndexOf is forward looking, LastIndexOf is reverse-looking.

Comment: @RonBeyer you are correct.